How can I order an dictionary array by key value?
I have an array with contains multiple dictinary objects. Each objects represents a user and contains a name key. I want the object alphabetically sorted in the array by the value of the name key.
Here a visual representation of what I want to end up with:
// We start with this
[
    {
        name: "foo",
        age: "24"
       },
    {
        name: "bar",
        age: "56"
    }
]

// We end up with this
[
    {
        name: "bar",
        age: "56"
    },
    {
        name: "foo",
        age: "24"
    }
]

